# Efficiently finding the last timestamp within a given timeframe

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

The problem is around a hypothetical online store; I will simplify the data for my particular issue.

Assume two tables: One holding the registration day for each customer

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customerID int,
    register DATE,
);
```

, and the second holding all the online visits of the customers

```
CREATE TABLE visits (
    customerID int,
    visit DATE,
);
```

**For each user, I would like to find the last day the user visited the online store within 7 days of registration, *in the most efficient way*.** If the user has not visited the store after registration, I should return NULL as the last visit day within 7 days following the registration.

I could of course *LEFT JOIN* customers with visits on *customerID* and, filter the *visit date* to be between the *registration day* and *that plus seven*, and finally get the *max date* for each *customer*.
However the initial join would result into a huge table and I'd like to avoid this computationally expensive operation.

Ideas are hugely appreciated!

Comment: instead of left join from customers to visits, can you not just get the max visit date of each customer from visits table and then join that result with customers??

Comment: @Kaus2b I don't believe I can cause how are you going to ensure that the max visit won't exceed day7 after registration. in that case

Comment: i was thinking in these terms `select customerID, visit
    from visits v1 where (select register from customers c where c.customerID = v1.customerID) = v1.visit`

Comment: @Kaus2b - That would list all visits, and not be as efficient as a simple JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most efficient:

```
SELECT  c.customerID, c.register,
        ( SELECT MAX(v.visit)
            FROM visits AS v
            WHERE v.customerID = c.customerID
              AND v.visit < c.register + INTERVAL 7 DAY
        ) AS last_date
    FROM customers AS c;
```

Indexes:

```
customers:  PRIMARY KEY(customerId)  -- is this what  you have?
visits:     INDEX(customerID, visit)  -- or perhaps PRIMARY KEY
```

Your concerns about "computationally expensive operation":

- Fetching rows is more costly than expression evaluation.
- The index I recommend for `visits` is "covering", so it looks only at the index.